# How to map one list and dictionary in python

Tags: python

List output of program

```
print ('list', L)
```

```
['A','B']
```

dictionary output of program after the manipulation of program is below

```
print ('dictionary', d)
```

dictionary  {'a':1,'b':2}

dictionary  {'a':1,'b':2}

Expected Out

`{'A':{'a':1,'b':2}, 'B': {'a':1,'b':2}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_out  = ['A', 'B']
dict_out1 = {'a':1,,'b':2}
dict_out2 = {'a':1,,'b':2}
exp_out   = {list_out[0]: dict_out1,
             list_out[1]: dict_out2}
```

Comment: dictionary outs are like this ` {'a':1,,'b':2}  {'a':1,,'b':2}`  there is no `dict_out1` and `dict_out2`

Comment: output of a program is  like ` {'a':1,,'b':2} {'a':1,,'b':2}`

Comment: You need to restate your question with a lot more detail. It is not clear at all.