# create new dictionary from mapping list into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create new dictionary by mapping list into dictionary, so the list item will be the key and the dictionary will be the value.

Students List :

```
[Student1,Student2,Student3]
```

dictionary:

```
{Math:90, CS:94, Since:89}
```

the expected result is one dictionary:

```
{
 "Student1":{
     Math:90
},
"Student2":{
     CS:94
},
"Student3":{
 Since:89

}
}
```

I tray this:

```
new_dic=dic()
new_dic = dic(zip(students,dic1)
```

output:
{
Student1:Math,
Student2:CS,
Student3:Since
}

but it give me unexpected result. also I try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480297/how-to-map-one-list-and-dictionary-in-python) and it didn't works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` along with some modification to reproduce the inner dict structure

```
names = ["Student1", "Student2", "Student3"]
values = {"Math": 90, "CS": 94, "Since": 89}
result = {name: {course: val} for name, (course, val) in zip(names, values.items())}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use:

```
a = ['student1','student2','student3']
b = { "Math":90 , "CS":94, "Since":89 }
c = {k1: {k2: v}  for (k1,k2,v) in zip(a, b.keys(), b.values())}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron I think your answer also right.